# meson: use library before declaring it

Tags: meson-build

Lets say your project looks like this:

meson.build:

```
project('myproject', 'cpp')

subdir('a')
subdir('b')
subdir('c')
```

a/meson.build:

```
mylib_a = library('mylib.cpp')
executable('a', 'main.cpp', link_with : [mylib_a])
```

with b/meson.build and c/meson.build looking similar.

If you would want to link the 'c' executable against mylib_a or mylib_b, you can simply add them to the array. But if you would want to link the 'a' executable against mylib_b or mylib_c you cannot do this without reordering the "subdir" commands. And If you would want to link 'c' against 'mylib_a' and 'a' against 'mylib_c', the only way, I could make it work is by putting the "executable('a', 'main.cpp', link_with : [mylib_a])" commands into meson.build instead of a/meson.build. This screws up the directory structure.

Is there any way I could link 'a' against mylib_c and 'c' against mylib_a without screwing up my directory structure?

UPDATE:
The meson authors say that there is no way to do this, but they will add one soon:
https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/8178

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing all executable's in the bottom of the root *meson.build* file. In this case all **mylib_a/b/c** variables will be available. You will also need to create in each subdirectory *meson.build* file **file_a/b/c** variables, e.g.

```
file_a = files('main.cpp')
```

and use them in corresponding **executable(...)**.

This may suffice your needs, but I suggest you to look towards using [subprojects](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html#subprojects) concept instead.

UPDATE

To avoid clutter if you have many sub-directories, libraries and executables you can use loop with [foreach](https://mesonbuild.com/Syntax.html#foreach-statements):

```
libs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lib_list = []
foreach l : libs
  lib_list += library(l, join_paths(l, 'mylib.cpp'))
endforeach

progs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
foreach p : progs
  exe = executable(p, join_paths(p, 'main.cpp'), link_with : lib_list)
endforeach
```

Comment: I know that putting the executables's in the button of the root meson.build file works, but this isn't exactly the tidiest way, because it clutters upper directories.

Comment: "clutters upper directories" - what does this mean?

Comment: I think its tidier if the command "executable('a', 'main.cpp', link_with : [mylib_a])" is writting in root/a/meson.build instead of "executable('a', 'a/main.cpp', link_with : [a/mylib_a])" written in root/meson.build. Becaue I don't want 50 executable(...) commands in my root/meson.build file.

Comment: @Kryptomatrix check my update, of course you can use dictionary or array of arrays to control source files, libraries to link with, etc. Note that you don't need meson.build's in subdirectories at all

Comment: @Kryptomatrix  will add one soon??? however it's just a discussion, it's likely be ended with no action... :) as it was already happened with even more obvious feature requests

Comment: Sorry for my optimism. What more obvious feature requests are you talking about?

Comment: example: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2904#issuecomment-725897085